# GLUT zooming in and out by wheel

Tags: opengl, glut, zooming

I have surfed a lot of sources and tried many varieties, but zooming still don't work. I can't change glprojection to gluPerspective, because in this case my prog don't draw anything. Here is approximate code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "glut.h"

#define windowSize 900.0
double zoomFactor = 1;
void reshape (int w, int h)
{
glViewport (0.0, 0.0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();
gluOrtho2D (-(GLdouble) w * zoomFactor, (GLdouble) w* zoomFactor, -(GLdouble) h* zoomFactor, (GLdouble) h* zoomFactor);
}
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
      if (button == 3 || button == 4 )
   { 
       if (state == GLUT_UP) zoomFactor += 0.05;
else zoomFactor -= 0.05;
   }
   else return;
   glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
}

Void display(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glBegin(GL_LINES); 
glVertex2f ((0),(0)); 
glVertex2f ((100),(0));
 glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINES); 
glVertex2f ((100),(0)); 
glVertex2f ((100),(100));
 glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINES); 
glVertex2f ((0),(0)); 
glVertex2f ((100),(1000));
 glEnd();
glFlush();

}

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(windowSize, windowSize);
glutInitWindowPosition(500,0);
glutCreateWindow("test");
glClearColor(0, 0.1,0.8,0.90);    
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, 200, 200,0);   
glutDisplayFunc( display );    
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutMainLoop(;

return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glutReshapeFunc` only tells GLUT which function to call, when the window size changes. It makes very little sense to call it in response to an input event as it will not call the reshape function.

Anyway, your problem is, that you placed setting the viewport and the projection in the reshape function. To all the tutorial writers out there: Stop doing that, it just ingrains bad habits into newbies.

Now please speak with me: *"Everything drawing related goes into the **display** function. The viewport is a drawing state and in every OpenGL program just a little bit more complex than 'Hello Triangle' the viewport is going to be changed several times drawing a single frame – for example when using framebuffer objects. I will thereby vow to never place calls to `glViewport` or projection matrix setup in the window reshape handler. I also vow to slap everyone in the face who writes code like this in my presence."*

Move the whole stuff in your reshape function into `display` (either set global variables, or use `glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_{WIDTH,HEIGHT})` to get the window dimensions in the display function) and call `glutPostRedisplay` in your mouse wheel function to trigger a redraw.

Comment: My neighbour was a bit scared by my vow speech. Zooming works, but there is no response for events of buttons 3 and 4. Could it be some mouse driver problems?

Comment: @SergeS: If you're using Linux/X11 you can use the `xev` tool to check which mouse button has which index. Usually button 4 and 5 are the mouse wheel.

Comment: Also after adding global int mouseX, mouseY and void motion(int x, int y) {mouseX=x; mouseY=y;} and in main glutPassiveMotionFunc(motion); and in display glViewport(mouseX, mouseY,glutGet(GLUT_INIT_WINDOW_WIDTH) ,glutGet(GLUT_INIT_WINDOW_WIDTH)); to zoom to cursor I got ridiculous behavior of zoom and bad reshaping, when image moves to the right corner if I on/off fullsize screen mode. Where should I use new mouse coords, if not in viewport and how to fix reshaping?